# Reading specific line in batch file

Tags: batch-file, ini

I'm trying to get a specific value's variable from a *setup.ini* with a batch script.

The variable's name is **ProductId** and I noticed that I have multiple variables with this name, but in different section.

This is my (dummy) *setup.ini*:

```ini
[install.msi]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
ProductId={123456}
key3 = value3

[mkl64.msi]
keyA = valueA
keyB = valueB
keyC = valueC   
ProductId={ABCDEF}
```

This is my *script.bat*:

```bash
@echo off

REM set consol page on UTF-8
chcp 65001 > nul

REM setup.ini directory (my file is in the same folder )
set "file=setup.ini"

REM variable to look for
set "variable=ProductId"

REM look for specific line in setup.ini
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| findstr /i "%variable%"') do (
    set "value=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo Il valore cercato è: !value!
    endlocal
)

chcp > nul

pause
```

With my script I got both `ProductId`, but I need to get only the one in the `[install.msi]` section -> `{123456}`.

Online I only find solutions on how to get a specific line, but not from a specific section also.

I tried something from chatGPT but nothing is working.

I was thinking about a possibile workaround: copy the `[install.msi]` section to a temporary file and then read the `ProductId` and I found something like this:

```bash
@echo off

REM set consol page on UTF-8
chcp 65001 > nul

REM setup.ini directory (my file is in the same folder )
set "file=setup.ini"

REM section to look for
set "section=[install.msi]"

REM file temp name
set "fileTemp=temp.ini"

REM create or overwrite file temp
echo. > "%fileTemp%"

REM flag to see if you are in the right section
set "sezioneTrovata="

REM look for the right section and copy in the temp file
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%file%" ^| findstr /n /r "%section%"') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    
    REM check if section is found
    if defined sectionFound (
        REM if you are in the right section copy
        echo !line! >> "%fileTemp%"
    ) 
)
chcp > nul

pause
```

But this is the output I see in the console:

```
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line! 
!line!
```

Comment: In your second script example, add a new line at line 2. ```setlocal enabledelayedexpansion```, and try it again.

Comment: @Compo the temp file generated was empty this time. But I found a solution on a Blog and I'm gonna post it

Comment: Looking at what you posted, it does not appear to be possible for your `temp.ini` file to be empty!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've answered similar before...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q77542525.txt"

SET "productid="
SET "insection="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED insection FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims={}" %%b IN ("%%e") DO IF "%%b"=="ProductId=" SET "productid=%%c"
 ECHO %%e|FINDSTR /b "[" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF "%%e"=="[install.msi]" (SET "insection=Y") ELSE (SET "insection=")
)

ECHO Product ID is %productid%

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

You would need to change the value assigned to `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

I used a file named `q77542525.txt` containing your data for my testing.

It is standard practice on SO to use the syntax `set "var=value"` for string
assignments as this ensures stray trailing spaces on the line are ignored.

First, initialise variables.

Read each line of the file to `%%e`.

If `insection` is set to any value, tokenise the line read using `{}` as delimiters & assign the first token to `%%b`, the second to `%%c` (see `for /?` from the prompt for docco, or thousands of examples on SO)

if `%%e` begins `[` then either the section found is of interest (set `insection` to something) or it is not of interest (set `insection` to *nothing*)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "searchSection=[install.msi]"

set "section="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (test.txt) do (
   if "%%b" equ "" set "section=%%a"
   if "!section!" equ "%searchSection%" set "%%a=%%b"
)

echo ProductId = %ProductId%
echo key3 = %key3%
```

Output:

```
ProductId = {123456}
key3 = value3
```

Note that this code extracts *all variables* in the search section, like `key3` in the example...